# Setting WebView size

Tags: java, android, view, webview

I am usign a WebView because of pan/zoom. In that WebView, I am adding some views dynamically.
That works fine, the views appear as desired, but when I zoom in the webView, the views's size is still the same.

What is the best way to re size them WITH the WebView?

And I also want to set the internal WebView size, so it is possible to Zoom out More.

**EDIT**

I add Views like this:

```
   View iv = inflater.inflate( R.layout.motor_block, null );
   WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
   wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
   settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
   settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   iv.setTag(currentKey);
   wv.addView(iv);
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything that you need to set in the `webView`.
As far as zooming is considered you can zoom only in the specified size of your `webView` inside your layout. So you may want to change the height and width of your `layout`/`webview`, that might help.

Else try this:

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Comment: The size of the webview in the main layout is ok, but the Views I add to the WebView dont get Re-sized with it, If I zoom in, I can see the bars at the side and the bottom get smaller (zooming in) but the views are still the same size

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, I want to make the Views change it size when I zoom in/out in the WebView.

Comment: The Views I am adding to the WebView (iv) dont change size when I zoom In the WebView, they remain the same.

Comment: @user2929866 They can't zoom in after a minimum size, are you able to zoom out and then zoom in?

Comment: They just remain the same, whether I zoom in or out. It zooms in (the scroll bars get smaller) but the Views that were added dont get bigger/smaller